# how to get count of a query which has joins

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I wrote a select query with  joins which is giving 100 records, But I need  to get the count of records of which same query fetching from DB

I have tried something mentioned below but its giving wrong count.

```
SELECT COUNT(vm.vendor_id)
         FROM vendor_master vm LEFT JOIN purchase_order po ON po.vendor_id=vm.vendor_id AND  vm.`is_active`=TRUE AND vm.`organization_id`=1



SELECT vm.vendor_id vendor_id,COUNT(po.Purchase_id) TOTAL_PURCHASES, vm.Vendor_Name,
MAX((SELECT vc.Contact_Name FROM vendor_contacts vc WHERE po.vendor_cont_id=vc.Vend_Cont_id)) contact_name,
SUM((SELECT SUM(pd.pur_amt) FROM purchase_details pd WHERE po.Purchase_id=pd.Purchase_id)) Total_amount,
(SELECT SUM(pm.Amount) FROM payment_master pm WHERE pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id) Paid,
(SUM((SELECT SUM(pd.pur_amt) FROM purchase_details pd WHERE po.Purchase_id=pd.Purchase_id)) -
(SELECT SUM(pm.Amount) FROM payment_master pm WHERE pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id)) Balance
FROM vendor_master vm LEFT JOIN purchase_order po ON po.vendor_id=vm.vendor_id AND  vm.`is_active`=TRUE AND vm.`organization_id`=1
GROUP BY vm.vendor_id
```

Above is actual query which I need to get count from

Comment: share sample tables data and it output

Comment: ' I need to get the count of records of which same query fetching from DB' i am unclear what this means

Comment: actual query is giving 100 records,now I need to get 100 as count instead of data

Comment: You have posted 2 queries - which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT vm.vendor_id vendor_id,COUNT(po.Purchase_id) TOTAL_PURCHASES, vm.Vendor_Name,
MAX((SELECT vc.Contact_Name FROM vendor_contacts vc WHERE po.vendor_cont_id=vc.Vend_Cont_id)) contact_name,
SUM((SELECT SUM(pd.pur_amt) FROM purchase_details pd WHERE po.Purchase_id=pd.Purchase_id)) Total_amount,
(SELECT SUM(pm.Amount) FROM payment_master pm WHERE pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id) Paid,
(SUM((SELECT SUM(pd.pur_amt) FROM purchase_details pd WHERE po.Purchase_id=pd.Purchase_id)) -
(SELECT SUM(pm.Amount) FROM payment_master pm WHERE pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id)) Balance
FROM vendor_master vm LEFT JOIN purchase_order po ON po.vendor_id=vm.vendor_id AND  vm.`is_active`=TRUE AND vm.`organization_id`=1
GROUP BY vm.vendor_id
) a;
```